# Is it possible to disable the GIF browser in Messages on a Moto G Power 2021?

Tags: google-messages, parental-control

My brother has a Moto G Power 2021 running Android 11 but wants to completely disable the GIF browser in the Messages app for SMS/MMS. I’d tried following various instructions online I could find for disabling it, but nothing seemed to work on his phone. Is this possible? I’m looking for any solution, whether with a system setting, a FamilyTime parental control, or blocking a particular service from using data as with NetGuard.

Comment: By GIF browser you mean the images selector shown in the keyboard like emojis? The keyboard is an own app you can replace, it has nothing to do with the messages app. Most keyboard apps also have their own settings where you can enable or disable emoticons and gifs.

Comment: @Robert I replaced the keyboard and the GIF browser is still there. It’s only in Messages. Disabling the GIF setting on the Gboard keyboard also did nothing.